# Azure Container Registry: got "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?"

Tags: docker, daemon, azure-container-registry

I have created Azure Container Registry
I am able to push an image from local to Azure container Registry.

I can pull or run any docker commands it always gives me the error saying

```sh
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
```

I am new to Azure, please is something i need to install or enable for docker

when I ran docker--version  it is showing the version perfectly

Comment: It appears that your statements are contradictory. Did you mean to say, "I am able to push" or "I am not able to push"? Also please review how to ask (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Azure. You must have Docker running on your local machine - the error itself is asking that question. Check that Docker is running on your local machine before trying to pull any images.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because used *'Azure Cloud Shell'* that doesn't support running the docker daemon.

To fix it need to run *CMD* or *Power Shell* and execute commands:

```sh
# az login

az acr login -n your_registry_name.azurecr.io

docker pull your_registry_name.azurecr.io/company_name/service_image:version
```

Comment: there is no need for the azurecr.io suffix, it is being omitted automatically. with the message: The login server endpoint suffix '.azurecr.io' is automatically omitted.

Answer (score 0):

For building and pushing image to Azure, you should user 'acr' command instead of 'docker'.
Follow these steps to build and push docker image to Azure Container Registry -

1. Open Azure Cloud Shell
2. Get necessary files

```
git clone https://github.com/tsrana/spring-boot-db2.git , 
cd spring-boot-db2
```

3. Create a Resource Group

```
az group create --name Docker_RG --location eastus
```

4. Create Container Registry

```
az acr create --resource-group Docker_RG --name tsrContainerRegistry --sku Basic
```

5. Build image and push to registry

```
az acr build --image tsr/hello-worldspring-boot-db2:v1 --registry tsrContainerRegistry --file Dockerfile
```